# Why can't I access a variable inside the method body in which it was passed in as a predicate to a LINQ function?

Tags: c#, lambda

I went to attempt to access a lambda variable inside a method, but I was surprised to see I couldn't. More specifically, regarding the code below, I went to access the `item` variable that I passed into the `IEnumerable.Any()` call as a predicate as a means to access that specific item's properties. But I was unable to do so.

Surely if I'm passing in the item as a parameter to the method then I should be able to access it within the method body. But this is not the case. Why is this? How can I change my code to be able to access `item`'s properties?

```
if (list.Any(item => item.questions == null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Item {item.Name} cannot be null"); //<-- Error here, "item" does not exist in current context.
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. A lambda expression is basically an anonymous method with its own scope.

What you could do instead is:

```
var nulls = list.Where(item => item.questions == null);

if (nulls.Any())
{
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Item {0} cannot be null"), nulls.First().Name)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expression `item => ...` defines the scope, *item* will be available only inside the lambda. If you need to find a specific item, try this:

```
var firstItemWithoutQuestions = list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.questions == null);
if (firstItemWithoutQuestions != null) 
{
   throw new ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have a look at your code:

```cs
if (
    list.Any(item => item.questions == null) // <-- item is only in scope of Any!
)
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Item {item.Name} cannot be null");
}
```

In line 2 of the snippet you have item, this item can only be used inside Any, but not inside the if-body.

you could do a `ForEach` over the collection, but the exception will than only be thrown on the first element

```
list.Foreach(item => 
{
    if(item.questions == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Item {item.Name} cannot be null");
}
```